# Integrate Yahoo Pipes into PHP App?

Tags: php, pipe

I just found this pipe.

http://pipes.yahoo.com/jonbishop/8vA1gjvl3RGqWknCBB50VA

I was just wondering if it was possible to integrate this into my web app? How would I go about doing it.

Basically, I have a form on my website - I would like this form to interact with this pipe to get the relevant data.

Could someone post a summary of what I would need to do to achieve this? I can then probably work it out from there. Using PHP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=overview

> Sharing a Pipe
>
> Once you've built a Pipe, you'll be
>   able save it on our server and then
>   call it like you would any other feed.
>   Pipes offers output in RSS 2.0, RSS
>   1.0 (RDF), JSON and Atom formats for maximum flexibility. You can also
>   choose to publish your Pipe and share
>   it with the world, allowing other
>   users to clone it, add their own
>   improvements, or use it as a
>   subcomponent in their own creations.

So you'd access it with any Feed Reader or XML lib you like. I am not aware of a public API for building Yahoo Pipes programmatically.